# fixed footer height

Tags: html, css, height, footer

I need a help about keeping my footer height fixed. Full of content and long pages, the footer is 10px. But when in login page or short pages, it will become lot lot bigger. [(preview)](http://www.1907.net/images/Gelsor.png) how can i fix this problem?

Comment: post your code so we can take a look, can't magically guess what the problem might be

Comment: We need to see some markup and CSS to help you.  Post a small sample of your code here, and you can also use [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to post a working sample we can look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your footer don't become more larger! it's just because that your Login page (and some other pages) have few contents (not as much as content on other pages of your site), so your footer seems to be broken and comes up!
So you should fix your footer at the bottom of your page. look at this http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Here is the sample for this solution [http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm)